# How to get the sumproduct in excel In a multiple condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In sheet1 column A I have Q1-Q4 then in column B I have different LanID and in column c I have different values.

After getting the Q1 only in sheet1 I have to find the value in sheet2 with matching the LanId found in sheet1. Please help.

P. S. Lanid and Q1-Q4 in sheet2 is not same with sheet1.

For example sheet 1

```
Quartile    Lanid.   Value
Q1            M1234      19  
Q1.           M5262.      20
Q2.           M0286.      12
```

Sheet 2

```
Quartile.    Lanid.  Value
Q1.          M51728.  67
Q3.          M1234.    23
Q4.          M5262.    45
```

So I have to find the sum product in sheet2  which is in Q1 sheet1 with the same lanId

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

Comment: Yeah. But how’d you do that? Like =sumifs(columnCsheet2, columnAsheet1,”Q1”, ......  how would I get the total of value of lanid in sheet2 referencing the Q1’s lanid? Help

Comment: Based on provided sample data, I'd guess `=SUMIFS(Sheet2!C:C,Sheet2!B:B,Sheet1!B2)` for Q1